# Uniform approximation. Two boundary layers?

Tags: asymptotics, approximation, perturbation-theory

Find uniform approximation up to order $O(\epsilon)$:
$$
\begin{cases}
\epsilon y''+\epsilon y' - y^2=-1-x^2 \\
y(0)=2 \\
y(1)=2
\end{cases}
$$
At $\epsilon=0$ solutions $\pm \sqrt{1+x^2}$ don't satisfy either of the B.C. Does this mean there are two boundary layers? E.g. to find the scaling of the boundary layer near $x=0$ let $y(x)=u(\epsilon^{\alpha}x)$ we get 
$$\epsilon^{2\alpha +1} u''+\epsilon^{\alpha +1} u' -u^2 = -1 - \epsilon^{-2\alpha} \bar{x}^2$$

where $\bar{x}=\epsilon^{\alpha}x$ is the new variable. Seems the only balance is when $\alpha=-\frac{1}{2}$ then we get (for the leading order term)
$$
\begin{cases}
u''-u^2=-1 \\
u(0)=2
\end{cases}
$$
Don't know how to further analyze this problem.
(Another possible balance is $\alpha=-1$ but this doesn't match the outer solution)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032643/obtain-the-leading-order-uniform-approximation-of-the-solution-to-epsilon-y?rq=1) will help?

Comment: when $\alpha=-1$ after multiplying the equation by $\epsilon$ we get $u''+\epsilon u'- \epsilon u^2 = -\epsilon - \epsilon^3 \bar{x}^2$. Why is this impossible? So leading order gives $u''=0$

Comment: OK, sorry, it doesn't work because $u''$ dominates all other terms.

Comment: On the RHS you should have $\epsilon^{2\alpha}$ (no minus). On the flip side the derivatives give negative powers of $\epsilon $.

Comment: but $x=\epsilon^{-\alpha} \bar{x}$

Comment: Oh, sorry, your notation is reversed relative to what I usually use. Then I agree. Perhaps you can get an ODE for $u^2$?

Comment: You mean to change function $v=u^2$ and find equation for $v$?

Comment: Possible. It doesn't seem to help, though.

Comment: This is an autonomous ODE $u''=f(u)$ so we can invert the problem and find $\bar{x}$ as a function of $u$. But the resulting expression doesn't seem to be nice...

Comment: I think that might be it, you have the correct outer solution, and there are boundary layers at 0 and 1, but it seems that the boundary layer equations are still very difficult to solve.